# I want to check if user is not logged in with PHP and then add a class to selector with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Checking if a user is logged in is no problem. But if the user is not logged in I want to add something like this:

```
$( "#tab-additional_information > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)" ).addClass( "jl_hidden" );
```

How do I embed this jQuery in a PHP if / else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can add PHP code in javascript like described below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if($_SESSION['is_logged_in'] == TRUE): ?>
    $( "#tab-additional_information > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)" ).addClass( "jl_hidden" );
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

Please, let me know if it not works. Also, change session name depends on your code.

Comment: This looks like PHP wrapped in jQuery. If I paste it in like this in my functions.php it doesn't work. And to show how little I know I have to ask you what you mean with "change session name depends on your code".

Comment: Okay. Can you please add this code `var_dump($_SESSION);` in php file ans share output.